# Places search box | Google Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I'm trying to implement [places search box for Google Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox?hl=ru) on my site. But when I'm typing in search box, I receive an error saying: `This API project is not authorized to use this API.` In Google Developer Console I enabled almost all what can be enabled:

[image: Google Developer Console]

What did I missed? By the way Google Map works perfectly. Error appears only when I'm using places search box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found missed API. It called `Google Places API Web Service`.